# I need help Identifing this set by the picture

Tags: technic

I have a blurry picture of a set I found at a LEGO fair, and I would like to  know what it is:

[image: blurry picture]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

That picture is quite blurry, but I'm pretty sure it's [8466 4x4 Off Roader](http://brickset.com/sets/8466-1/4X4-Off-Roader) from 2001:

[image: 8466]

The wheels in the picture look like they are metallic silver, and I think this is the only set of this size with metallic silver wheels and lime accents.